# How to understand DKIM signing domains?

Tags: postfix-mta, dkim

So i have a mail server say "mailer.com". Postfix handles mail for mailer.com also for "virtual.com" (postfix virtual domain).

So, when i create the DKIM key pair:
`opendkim-genkey -s mail -d example.com`

Which domain do i use here? mailer.com or virtual.com?
Then i put the public key in TXT record on the virtual.com domain?

FYI I used this guide:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-dkim-with-postfix-on-debian-wheezy

Answer (score 0):

You need to create keys for each domain you want to sign messages for and put appropriate DNS records in each domain DNS zone.